# How to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+2)e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+2)e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-x$

I tried factoring $x$ then writing it as $1/x$ and applying l'Hospital, I got the answer $3$ but my book say it should be $1$.

Comment: i fixed it , this is the limit

Comment: it should be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you allowed to do? The easiest is to expand $e^{-\frac{1}{x}} \sim 1-\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x^2}$

EDIT: Ok, another way is to rewrite it and set $\frac{1}{x} = t$:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{-t}-1}{t} + 2e^{-t}
$$
and recognize the definition of a derivative in the first term and take the limit

Comment: How do I know to expand in that form?

Comment: This is Maclaurin series expansion, you expand $e^t$ as $t$ gets close to 0

Answer (score 3):

Like Ennar, set $1/x=t$ to get $$\lim_{t\to0^+}\dfrac{(1+2t)-e^t}t\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{t\to0^+} e^t} =2-\lim_{t\to0^+}\dfrac{e^t-1}t=?$$

Comment: Very nice, the last limit is $\left.\frac d{dt}(e^t)\right|_{t=0} = 1$, +1 for no l'Hospital.

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to\infty$,
$$
e^{-1/x}=1-\frac1x+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
(x+2)e^{-1/x}-x
&=x+1+O\left(\frac1x\right)-x\\
&=1+O\left(\frac1x\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you let $t = \frac 1 x$, then 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+2)e^{-\frac 1 x}-x 
&= \lim_{t\to 0^+}(\frac 1 t + 2)e^{-t}-\frac 1 t\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{(2t+1)e^{-t}-1}{t}\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{2e^{-t}-(2t + 1)e^{-t}}{1}\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0^+}(1-2t)e^{-t} = 1
\end{align}

Comment: @oren revenge, seems to me you might have forgotten the minus sign when applying l'Hospital which would give your answer.